# why gitlab runner don't use my custom npm registry but use the default npm registry

Tags: node.js, npm, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I installed a gitlab runner on my window machine

and I run terminal input "npm config set registry http://my/custom/npm/registry"

[image]

and then i trigger a pipeline on my gitlab web page

[image]
i saw the terminal pannel show me a default registry value after run "npm config get registry"

why ??

did the gitlab runner doesn't use my npm config on the local machine ?

also, i use nrm to switch the npm registry, i got the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving your `npm config set registry https://custom-registry.example.com` inside your job specification instead of on your host. So for example:

```
npm_dependencies:
  stage: npm
  before_script:
    - npm config set registry https://custom-registry.example.com
  script:
    - npm config get registry
    - npm install
```

Comment: yes! i use this way to solve my problem, but i puzzle in why on my mac machine i'm set the npm registry on the teminal, gitlab pipeline can access the custom registry correctly